# Can OAuth be implemented with two factor authentication using a mobile device and QRCodes?

Tags: java, android, oauth, oauth-2.0, qr-code

I've been looking into OAuth to see if it can be used in a project I'm working on. I'm starting to doubt if its possible. It's based on two factor authentication with a mobile device.

Essentially I'll have a login page where upon successful login a QRCode will appear on screen. The user will be prompted to scan this code with their android device (An app I'm making myself) which will authenticate them with the server.

I'm not sure if this fits with the OAuth paradigm so I'm thinking I may need to design my own protocol instead.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think OAuth finds a place here, you have only one server and your mobile user is not known to it. OAuth is used when a client (eg:web-app, android app) needs to talk to a server (eg:Google Plus) on behalf of an end-user that there owns some resource (eg: end user google drive files), protecting their credentials. Eg: You cannot/dont'need to know their password in Gplus, GPlus tells you they are authorized users there and allows you to do things on their behalf, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth

Why you user does not insert username and password in the Android App, without the QRcode ? I dont' think you are adding any security with this qrcode that anybody can scan, look at Google 2 Step: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-step_verification they send an sms

Comment: The way I had originally planned this was to generate a random secure number and display it as a QRCode on the user's computer screen. This user would then scan the code, encrypting it with a secret password stored on their device, and send the result directly to the server. The server knows this is coming from the user as it is encrypted with their unique password associated with their account and only stored on their phone.

When a user first registers with the website it will prompt them to install the app and scan a QRCode containing their secret password to store on their device.

Comment: I think one difference with google example is that you know that somebody that installed your mobile app and that scanned that initial code is answering you but this somebody could be many, while google sends sms only to one phone, each time needed. Q: Is the mobile used as sort of crypto device for logging in server or does it interact more with server ?

Comment: I was only intending on using the mobile device for scanning the codes and sending them back to the server.

Comment: I would generate and store (the first time) the 'password' on mobile. First QRCode should identify web user (temporarily?). QRCode value is sent back to server (HTTPS) with 'password', server answers with ID to use later on to send scanned codes. Pro: Server is able to accept only one (the first) phone to identify a user and 'password/phone identifier' is never displayed.