# how to use GoogleAuthenticator for tfa (two-factor authentication) in a custom non-google login webapp

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-api-client, google-authentication, google-authenticator

ok, I've spent 2 hours googling on what it is & how to use it in a web-application! but no success.

Most of the links talk about scanning codes or entering some key in the GoogleAuthenticar mobile app and it'll return changing verification codes every 30 seconds.

Few things :

1. The webapplication has it's own login. That means users don't login using Google into the webapp.
2. If an attacker gets the user's password, he sees the QRcode as the next-step, which he can scan directly with the GoogleAuthenticator app in his mobile (as far as it appears to me). How is it tied to user's mobile only ?
3. In various sites, it mentions a shared secret between user & server, that means at the time of signup, we provide the user the shared-secret, which he can use in her mobile GoogleAuthenticator app and then use it while reading the QR code ?
4. In the above case, how to proceed if the secret is lost or forgotten by the user ? Use forget secret to send the secret again to user's email ?

I am confused about how can it be implemented in a fashion when it's a non-google non-android application!

All I get is that, it's just a concept asking for our own implementation with some help from the source-code of the GoogleAuthenticator. Please correct me ?

What I think is the solution is that, we have to write our own mobile-app, just like this guy mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364446/can-oauth-be-implemented-with-two-factor-authentication-using-a-mobile-device-an), although I'm still not sure how will the secret between the mobile-app and the server will be unique with each installation of that app such that it identifies a particular user only or is there any way to write our own app and use GoogleAuthenticator mobile app without having Google-login in our webapp ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Authenticator (the mobile application) implements the *Time-based One-time Password Algorithm*.  In the scenario you are asking about, two-factor authentication would work as follows:

- The user generates a one-time password to be validated by a server application.
- The server would verify the password using the procedure detailed by the TOTP algorithm.

The password generation on the user device can be performed by any application implementing TOTP which has been "configured" for your user account.  *Configured* here means having shared a secret with the server, as you mention yourself in the question.

Now, trying to answer your questions:

1. The fact your application uses its own set of user credentials or Google's has no direct effect on two-factor authentication.  No matter what these credentials are, you need a way to identify your user (the *username*) in order to be able to proceed to the validation of its TOTP password, because you need to know *who the user is*.  Said another way: using TOTP and using the Google Authenticator application does **not** imply having to use Google credentials on your site.
2. I'm not sure I understand correctly.  The configuration of the Google Authenticator app for each account is performed *only once*.  If an attacker is sitting right behind your back and takes a photo of your screen while you configure Google Authenticator, then yes, he'd be able to configure its own application with your credentials reading the same barcode you're using.  Nevertheless, he'd also need your credentials (proper) in order to perform the login and *then* provide the one-time TOTP password.  Anyway, this is a security problem which stems from how the user improperly handles its own credentials and you could be subject to similar problems no matter the technology you use.  To make an imperfect metaphor, it's like asking "*if the user leaves the pin card with the codes on the table, an attacker sees it and steals a photo of it, could it use them?*". Sure, he could.
3. Yes, reading the barcode is one of the ways you can configure the application and sharing the secret between the client application and the server.  You can use other means, such as entering the key manually into the application, but using the QR code is quicker and much less error prone.  You won't even need to generate the QR code, because you could use Google's Web APIs as I explained in [the blog post](http://thegreyblog.blogspot.com/2011/12/google-authenticator-using-it-in-your.html?q=google+authenticator) you were reading when you asked me to answer this question.  In fact, the Java server side library described there uses the Google Web API's and returns you an URL for the user to check out and read its own QR.  If you want to build your own QR logic, go on, but there's no compelling reason you should do that if you're eligible to use Google's APIs (which is something you should check anyway).
4. If the secret is lost it depends on your own policy, if it's your own application.  First of all, you should invalidate the old secret *immediately upon user notification*.  Then, you could use the *scratch codes* you may have given the user upon creation of the TOTP secret to verify his own identity.  If he has lost the scratch codes too, you'd probably want to fall back to some other ways to verify his identity such as using some kind of backup information in his account (backup telephone numbers, security questions, etc.).  Once the user identity is verified according to your standards, you would issue a new credential and would begin from the start: that is, reconfiguring the Google Authenticator using a new QR and/or a new secret key.

To summarise: yes, you can use the Google Authenticator application as your client front-end if you want to: there's no need to build another one.  The only thing which you should into account is that Google Authenticator uses 30-second windows in its TOTP implementation: the server side logic verifying the TOTP password will have to use the same window size (which is, IIRC, the standard value proposed by the [TOTP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238)).

Comment: thanks for taking the time and answering, but then it's not a 2-factor authentication, right ? Apart from user-password, there's no second authentication mechanism associated to an user, since the barcode can be read correctly by any attacker who has somehow passed the first authentication.

Comment: You're welcome. It's a 2-factor authentication (exactly how Google is doing it, BTW). The QR code is used *exclusively* to configure the client application *once*. Just imagine it's a way to transfer your username and the key to your client application. When you need to *authenticate* and the server is asking for your TOTP password, you'll open your Google Authenticator app and insert the number it's showing at that moment. The server will *authenticate you* validating the 1-time password using the TOTP algorithm. **That is** the "second authentication mechanism" you're talking about.

Comment: so just to make sure that I understood it correctly. When a user signs-up, password and a Barcode is given to him. So whenever the 2nd authentication is required, there's no bar-code to scan, since it's already given at the time of signup. All he has to do, is just generate a new sequence of digits using the Google Authenticator app. Now, since it's only him who has this bar-code (a different bar-code is given to every user), so the generated password should be correct and the server would be able to verify it using the barcode (which is saved in db for that user) and the entered sequence ?

Comment: @coding_idiot, basically yes, it's correct, but please remember that the barcode is just a way to encode the shared secret and deliver it to the user.